# How to make QDateTimeEdit widget of qt designer in 24hr clock format

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer, qdatetime

I am working on `UI` design which I am designing in `qt desginer`. In `qt designer`, there is a widget `QDateTimeEdit` through which we can select the date and time. I have added it and it looks like below:

[image]

I have added two widgets from start and end date time. I have also added calendar popup so for date, I can select using calendar. For time, I can adjust it by typing time on keyboard.

By default it comes with `AM` `PM`. Is there any way we can change this to 24hr clock format. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the format of the QDateTimeEdit in the displayFormat property:

[image]

Comment: I noticed that if I remove `AP` from the display format, it then starts to accept time in 24hr format. Is that correct.? What does AP means.? AM/PM.?

Comment: @SAndrew Exactly, the time format is based on QTime: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#toString, and the date format on QDateTime: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toString. Read the docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#displayFormat-prop